# Just learning cURL and exec not returning boolean value

Tags: php, curl

Morning,

Am just starting to learn cURL. Have found some good tutorials but most say that exec will return true or false. I've tried using console to check but nothing is output.

```
   <?php
   $curl = curl_init('http://www.techflirt.com');
   $result = curl_exec($curl); // will return true or false
   if($result === false) {
     echo "<script>console.log('Whoops!')</script>";
   }
   else {
    echo "<script>console.log('TRUE')</script>";
   }
   curl_close($curl);
   print $result;
   ?>
```

Comment: have you followed the [instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) in the docs?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something `console.log` is JavaScript not PHP. Turn on display errors - I'm pretty sure there will be a `fatal error` in there which will kill the script before it gets to `print $result`

Comment: Apologies missed the script tags. (senior moment :-)) Now outputs TRUE